# CakePHPを採用している国内サイトの調べ方は？

Tags: php, cakephp

CakePHPを採用している事を公表している国内のサイトについて知りたいです。
CakePHP1系か2系かも分かった方がより有用ですね。

うまい調査法があるでしょうか？

Comment: この質問はリスト型質問にあたるのであまりいい質問ではありませんでした。回答してくださった方ありがとうございます。

Comment: Wantedlyで調べるという回答がよい調査法を示唆しているのでそれを主眼にした質問に変更しました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

興味があったので求人サイトの Wantedly で調べてみました。

検索してみたところ

https://www.wantedly.com/internship/japan/all/cakephp

https://www.wantedly.com/search?page=1&q=CakePHP&t=projects

（他にも多数ありますが）

- ランサーズ

  - https://www.wantedly.com/projects/6376
- BASE

  - https://www.wantedly.com/projects/6571

などが使っているみたいですね。

Comment: 面白い調べ方ですね！ランサーズはRailsと一緒に使ってるみたいですね。

Answer (score 3):

どの言語、どのフレームワークで構築しているか？という情報は、セキュリティ上のリスクになるため、インタビューや求人情報、勉強会資料などから間接的に知ることはできるものの、積極的に公表するサイトは無いと考えたほうが良いのではないでしょうか？もし質問が、「任意のサイトが、CakePHPを使っているかどうか調べるにはどうすれば良いですか？」というような形なら、かなり具体的にお話しできるのですが・・・。